# Form submits on page refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my HomeController I have a function that handles a form submit from the home page.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string message){

   // Do something

   return View();
}
```

I'm taking this value and storing it in the DB. Everything is working fine there. But what I'm noticing is that after I submit an initial value, I refresh the page, and it re-submits the form with that same value. Each time I refresh the page, it submits a message to the DB.

Thoughts? I haven't seen anyone else online running into this issue.

Comment: are you using get requests? If you use get requests to submit the form then the url will keep submitting every time you refresh it or go to it

Comment: I believe the only way this would get hit is if you issue a submit (button) on your page.  refresh generates get requests, not posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want follow [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) design pattern.

It basically redirects to another page, after processing data.

For example,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string message){

   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       // Save data to database.

       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }
   // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
   return View();
}
```

Comment: ModelState.IsValid remains true for both a form submit via button press, as well as a page refresh.

Comment: ModelState.IsValid will always return true if the model is valid. This is not the point here; the point is to redirect to another page after successful processing the posted data. If user refreshes the browser, s/he will be refreshing the another page which is HttpGet ([Idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)).

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Yeah, I may need to refactor some as much of this functionality is done on a single page.